# Another assembly referencing the old dll

Tags: c#, assemblies, .net-assembly

I have 2 assemblies lets call them A and B. I've assigned strong names to them and now the problem arises that assembly B is looking for the old version of assembly A.
**EDIT2: If I delete AssemblyB the problem persists so it might just be VS2008 looking for the old version? Also via fusionlog I see the following warning: wrn application configuration file binding redirects disallowed. Does this have anything to do with it? **

I get multiple errors of the same kind, here's one snippet:

```
You must add a reference to assembly 'AssemblyA, Version=1.2.4737.25316, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The strong named AssemblyA inside the project shows these properties:
[image]

Inside app.config I've placed this piece of code:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="AssemblyA" culture="neutral"
    publicKeyToken="a22e30ac6a0edfc0"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.4737.25316" newVersion="1.3.0.19440"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

But this does not work. I have access to the source of both assemblies.

EDIT: If I delete the strong named and add the old (weak named) dll to the project it will give an error asking about the strong named version

```
You must add a reference to assembly 'AssemblyA, Version=1.3.0.19440, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a22e30ac6a0edfc0'.
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some DLL's still referred to the old (weak named) version of other DLL's. Luckily the assemblies came with the source so I had to recompile everything including a key.

After that another error came up along the lines of "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"

To fix this I added the following in the app.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
            <assemblyIdentity name="Assemblyname" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="3a5628535d42dbed"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.3.0.15233" newVersion="1.3.0.40647" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: What if I'm on a project without an app.config

Comment: @ShadyM.Najib Depends on what kind of project you're working on. You could try adding it via this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658(v=vs.90).aspx. In case you're working with SSIS script component you could try changing this file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DtsDebugHost.exe.config, place the piece of code between the <configuration> tags.

Comment: Actually I mean a project type that doesn't support a config file.. Windows 8 project for eg :D

Comment: @ShadyM.Najib Sorry can't help you there. You could try google, found this: http://www.geekchamp.com/forums/windows-8-development/app-config---web-config-missing-in-windows-8-apps--what-is-the-equivalent.